# Preventing multiple login in asp.net mvc (forms authentication)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

we are bulding a simple website with a user login. A special requirement is that a user can only be used one time concurrently. So the login credentials can only be used to login again, when the user logged out (or the session expired), so the same login credential is not used by multiple users.

I could not find any "standard" way of doing this. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done rather simply?

My first guess would be some static class holding the current logins.

Comment: I would rather save in the DB the login status and a login time (so you can double check timeouts). But ask yourself if you really want to implement this: keep in mind that if the client turns off the machine and tries to logon again there is the risk that it will be detected as a second login and may be denied (so you need to consider this scenario). Also consider the scenario where the user leaves the computer and wants to keep working on his tablet/phone, either he will be denied login or he needs to remember to log off from his machine.

Comment: @Tallmaris This requirement sometimes comes from certain security certifications. But you are right it sounds like trouble and it realy is.